# Popcorn Time stuck in apt-get

Tags: 14.04, apt

So I'm just coming back to Ubuntu after some time away, running 14.04 and I've gotten things customized the way I like them, more or less.  At one point I'd attempted to download "Popcorn-Time."  I ran into some issues of some sort and decided to remove it/that it wasn't worth the trouble.

Something from the install process seems to be "stuck" in apt-get though.  I'm having issues getting new packages and I'm getting this message:

```
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up popcorn-time (0.3.2~webupd8~6) ...
Downloading Popcorn Time...
--2015-09-06 11:25:00--  http://cdn.popcorntime.io/build/Popcorn-Time ...
Resolving cdn.popcorntime.io ...
Connecting to cdn.popcorntime.io (cdn.popcorntime.io)|45.33.69.37|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-09-06 11:25:00 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Popcorn Time is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package popcorn-time (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
...

Errors were encountered while processing:
 popcorn-time
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've omitted a couple of lines there, but I think you get the idea.  This is occurring when I try to install most packages using apt-get, maybe all packages.  It seems like it's interfering, and frankly I'd like it to not try to install popcorn time every time I install any package.

Any ideas?

Comment: disable the popcorn webupd8 PPA and try again.

Comment: @Ron I tried that, no dice.  See my comment on the answer below.  Turned out I needed to remove it from dpkg's database.

Answer (score 3):

Turned out I needed to remove it from dpkg:

```
dpkg -r popcorn-time
```

And that took care of it for me.  Thanks again for the help and suggestions everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Since its site seems to be down try removing the popcorntime.io PPA: E.g. 
[See this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

Then do an `sudo apt-get update` and apt should be ok.

Comment: No dice.  Still there.  The remove command doesn't seem to work?  `sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:webupd8team/popcorntime`  produces the result  `Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:webupd8team/popcorntime'.  Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @DavidFoerster This is an attempt to answer the question.